# Can you please help me to find the noun of the verb "is" in the following sentence?

Tags: phrases, verbs, nouns

I can not tell what the noun for the verb *is* in *of what is* is here in this long sentence from an eponymous 2001 book on Andy Warhol by DHD Buchloh:

> I shall, however, want to claim that there is a dominant trend toward the representation of a body-in-pieces, *of what **is***, in Kleinian theory, termed the part object, that runs, like an insistent thread, a sustained subtext, through much of American artistic production (and through its painting and sculpture, in particular) in the 1950s and 1960s.

Comment: What is the subject.

Comment: There is an X of what is termed Y that runs through Z. 'What' refers to Y. It is 'the part object'. Y is 'represented' by a 'body-in-pieces'. Turgid stuff.

Comment: Which noun are you talking about? The subject? The subject complement? Something else? To make it easier for you to parse, you can rephrase it as “a trend toward the representation of a body-in-pieces, toward the representation of something that is termed the _part object_ in Kleinian theory, something that runs like an insistent thread through much of the American artistic production of the 1950s and 1960s, particularly painting and sculpture”. It is a very long sentence that tries to stuff in too many constituents and sometimes places them in ways that make it harder to parse.

Comment: @NigelJ Thanks for the reply.  So, what is **X** here? Thanks again.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for the reply. So, are they using rules for parellel structures? I mean-  "the representation of a body-in-pieces, **of what is**," actually means "the representation of a body-in-pieces, **the representation of what is**,". Thanks.

Comment: @krishekesi The _of_ in “of what is” is the same _of_ as in “of a body-in-pieces” just before it. The two prepositional phrases are parallels: the representation of A, of B(, of C, of E, of F, etc.). This is a common rhetorical effect; compare, “We have an innate fear of letting go, of losing our inhibitions, of setting ourselves free, of doing what we want”. Note that “of what is” is not a phrase of its own—it’s just the preposition _of_ with the nominalised clause “what is termed the part object in Kleinian theory”. So “a body-in-pieces” is parallel with “what is termed…”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks a lot for your time and help. I think I got it now.  Here, "**what**" is not a regular pronoun with an antecedent as in "I saw a car **what(or which)** was blue". Here, we have an antecedent for "**what/which**". But in the following sentence(I got it from this forum) "This is an illustration of **what** is normally considered [to be] a Queen Anne house", we don't have an antecedent for "**what**". So, "**what**" in the original sentence( ie ... ,of what, in Kleinian theory,...) doesn't have an antecedent too.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet would you like to suggest me one or two grammar books? It seems like you are very good at English grammar. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

krishe, first let's strip away parenthetical material that doesn't affect the basic structure; we're left with the prepositional phrase "of what is termed the part object".  "Of" is the preposition, and "what is termed the part object" is the object of the preposition.  This prepositional object is a noun clause cast in the present passive ("is termed").  The relative pronoun "what" is the subject of the passive verb phrase, and the noun phrase "the part object" is the object of the passive verb phrase.  Lune